# Paramiko error using put

Tags: python, paramiko

Hi I am using paramiko 1.7.6 "fanny" on microsoft windows xp v2002 service pack3 with python 2.4.2

I have the follwing script:

```
import paramiko

hostname='blah' 
port=22
username='blah'
password='blah'
fullpath='\\\\root\\path\\file.xls'
remotepath='/inbox/file.xls'

self.client= paramiko.SSHClient()
self.client.load_system_host_keys()
self.client.connect(hostname,port,username,password)
sftp = self.client.open_sftp()
sftp.put(fullpath,remotepath)
```

the error I get is:

```
sftp.put(fullpath,remotepath))

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 577, in put
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 337, in stat
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 628, in _request
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 675, in _read_response
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 701, in _convert_status
IOError: [Errno 2] /inbox/file.xls is not a valid file path
```

but the path definitely exists (I can move into it using sftp.chdir('inbox')) I
have also tried moving into the folder and using put but I get the exact same
error (did take out inbox prefix)

Has anyone had this issue?

Cheers
matt

Comment: have you tried using back slash instead : __remotepath='\\inbox\\file.xls'__  ??

Comment: You say '/inbox' fails but 'inbox' works when tested manually - are you sure you need the first slash, ie inbox is the root directory?

Answer (score 1):

`IOError: [Errno 2] /inbox/file.xls is not a valid file path`

This is your error, which means that /inbox isn't a valid path. You probably meant to use

`remotepath='inbox/file.xls'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

The signature specifies sftp_client.py
   def put(self, localpath, remotepath, callback=None, confirm=True):

most of the forums answered referred the first argument as remotepath.

if we change the first one as local path and the second one as remote path,
  it works fine.

No issues with this.